# Getting a "Login Untried" Error in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I am getting a login untried when trying to access a Rest API with authentication. I am using WS Play within Lagom. The login request looks something like:

```
val reqLogin = ws.url(loginURL)
  .withAuth(userName, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC)
  .execute()
```

The message from the follow-up query is a 401 unauthorized error. Here is how I attempt the query after the above login attempt:

```
val loginResponse = Await.result(reqLogin, Duration(60, "seconds"))
val cookies = loginResponse.cookies
val queryResponse = ws.url(queryURL)
    .withCookies(cookies.toSeq :_*)
    .execute()
val queryResponseOutput = Await.result(queryResponse, Duration(60, "seconds"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first request, you are logging in using [HTTP Basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Does the site that you're using support HTTP basic authentication? Typically when a site does support it, it won't send you a cookie, rather, it will expect the login credentials to be sent with every request. So, when using HTTP basic authentication, there should be no need to login at the login URL, instead, add the username and password to the request to `queryUrl`. If that doesn't work, then that could mean the site you are making requests on doesn't support HTTP Basic authentication.

The other type of login is to submit the username and password in a login form, and then site you are logging into will send you back a cookie which you can use for subsequent requests. That appears to be what you're trying to do, but to do that, you can't use the `withAuth` method, rather, you have to find out what the username/password parameters are in the sites login form, and send a form with those parameters set. I can't tell you what those parameters are, that is entirely dependent on the site you're logging into, you'll have to look at the documentation for that site, or at the HTML it outputs on the login page. When you get back the response to the login request, you should check the response code to see if it was successful. The documentation for how to submit form parameters using Play WS can be found [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaWS#Submitting-form-data), here's an example of what it might look like:

```scala
val reqLogin = ws.url(loginURL)
  .post(Map(
    "yourusernameparameter" -> Seq(userName),
    "yourpasswordparameter" -> Seq(password)
  ))
```

To make clear, the `yourusernameparameter` and `yourpasswordparameter` fields above need to be replaced with whatever the site you're logging into requires. You may also need to enter CSRF tokens.

Comment: This very helpful. Thank you. Makes a lot of sense. And I can confirm that the site I am accessing is not basic authentication. Though, the only catch is that ".setContentType" is applicable only for the Java implementation. Not clear to me from [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaWS#Submitting-form-data) what the Scala equivalent would be.

Comment: Any further insight would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Oh you're right, sorry about that, I've updated for the Scala API.